# Hibernate mapping trouble - A Foreign key referring X from Y has the wrong number of column. should be 0

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

What is the reason for the following error in `Hibernate`?

> org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key referring X.class has the
>   wrong number of column. should be 0

Child entity is;

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Patient_Details")
public class Patient implements Serializable  {

    @Id
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="userID")
    private UserAuthentication userAuth;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "patient2")
    private List<Insurance> insurances = new ArrayList<>();

    // other fields, constructor, getters, setters
}
```

And the parent entity;

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "insurance")
public class Insurance implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long insuranceID;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="patientID",nullable=false)
    private Patient patient2;

    // other fields, constructor, getters, setters
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the shared primary key. Solution is to use `@MapsId`

Change the id reference in the `Patient` class;

```
@Id
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="userID")
private UserAuthentication userAuth;
```

with the below example;

```
@Id
private long userID;

@MapsId
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "userID")
private UserAuthentication userAuth;
```